# Unable to pass W3C Validation

Tags: w3c-validation

I am trying to get something to pass the W3C Validation (this is my first HTML web design class). I keep getting the same error (***Text not allowed in element ul in this context.***).  There are five of these errors, they are all in the same location but on different lines.

If anyone could please look at this and tell me what I have done wrong. Thank You.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Fish Creek Animal Hospital Services</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Fish Creek Animal Hospital</h1>
<div><b><a href="index.html">Home &nbsp;</a>
<a href="services.html">Services &nbsp;</a>
<a href="askvet.html">Ask the Vet &nbsp;</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contact &nbsp;</a></b></div>
<ul>
<li><strong>Medical Services</strong></li>
We offer state of the art equipment and technology.
<li><strong>Surgical Services</strong></li>
Full range of surgical procedures including orthopedics and emergency surgeries.
<li><strong>Dental Care</strong></li>
A dental exam can determine whether your pet needs preventative dental care such as scaling and polishing.
<li><strong>House Calls</strong></li>
The elderly, physically challenged, and multiple pet households often find our in-home veterinary service helpful and convenient.
<li><strong>Emergencies</strong></li>
At least one of our doctors is on call every day and night.
</ul>
<div>
<small><i>Copyright &copy; 2013 Fish Creek Animal Hospital
<a href="mailto:csigman1@gmail.com">csigman1@gmail.com</a>
</i></small>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you're using this tool here, but I can't be sure of this. http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options

Answer (score 2):

Any section that has text, which has not been wrapped in a HTML tag will cause you this error. Here, it's the list. Each item (block of text) within the list requires a `<li>` tag wrapping the whole content.

```
<ul>
 <li>text content</li> <!-- correct -->
 <li></li>text content <!-- incorrect -->
</ul>
```

So in your script, change all items from this:

```
<li>
  <strong>Surgical Services</strong></li>
  Full range of surgical procedures including orthopedics 
  and emergency surgeries.
```

To this:

```
<li>
  <strong>Surgical Services</strong>
  Full range of surgical procedures including orthopedics 
  and emergency surgeries.
</li>
```